# Sales sums / grouping - where to perform these functions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have models for Products and Statement_Sales and want to perform various Sum and Group actions for presenting sales reports and basic analytics in my views. Where is the best place to put these, Model or Controller, and how do I then access them in my views?

At the moment I can easily bring in line by line sales date using something like this in my view:

```
 <%  @product.statement_sales.each do |sales| %>
 <td><%= sales.units %></td>
 <% end %>
```

But this is line by line data, I want to be able initially give a total by date, then totals for 7 days, 1 Month, 3 Months, 1 Year etc etc.

In console i've figured out grouping by date using:

```
 p.statement_sales.group(:date).sum(:units)
```

Not sure how to bring that into the app and take it beyond grouping by one date.

Fairly new to Rails (after years of PHP) so hitting a few walls with the differerent approach. I'm sure this is actually quite easy!! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule of thumb is "fat model, skinny controller". This means you should push most of your logic into the model and keep the controller actions as simple as possible.

For you particular scenario, you will want to look into Rails [scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes). Scopes allow you to encapsulate and reuse a complicated query such as the ones you describe above. For example, assuming you have a `StatementSale` model that `belongs_to` a `Product` (I don't know the specifics of your object graph):

```
class StatementSale < ActiveRecord::Base  
  scope :units_by_date, group(:date).sum(:units)
end
```

This would allow you to call `@product.statement_sales.units_by_date` in your view.

You can also build a scope that takes a parameter. For example, say you wanted to be able to pass in a parameter to group by dynamically, your scope would look like this:

`scope :units_grouped_by, lambda { |p| group(p).sum(:units) }`

Without knowing the details of the more complicated queries that you'd want to perform, scopes are definitely the place to house all of that logic.

Comment: The scope approach doens't seem to work, I get an error. But have tried the follwoing that does seem to work:  def self.units_by_date
   group(:date).sum(:units)
  end

Comment: What is the error you are seeing? Adding the class method is an alternative to using a scope, but you should be able to use both interchangeably.